# Is the message ts the ID of the message?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am trying to build an app that syncs a forum with slack. Posting on either site will reflect on the site, but I need the ID of messages in Slack. [The Slack Documentation](https://api.slack.com/events/message) says that

> the `text` property is the text spoken, and `ts` is the unique (per-channel) timestamp.

Does this mean that the `ts` field is effectively the ID for that channel?

Comment: it is the timestamp as far I can see

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the timestamp (ts) is the ID of a message within a channel.

The complete ID of a message over multiple Slack workspaces is:

- Slack workspace ID -> channel ID -> message timestamp

You can verify by looking for example on the API method [chat.delete](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.delete) for deleting a message. There you also need to give the channel ID and the timestamp to identify the message to be deleted. (Plus the token, which is linked 1:1 to the slack team).

Comment: Thanks! They more clearly explain this in the documentation

Comment: [It is documented](https://api.slack.com/messaging/retrieving#individual_messages), but I think the real problem is that they didn't just create separate fields named `timestamp` and `id`, where `id` already includes both the channel ID and timestamp. That would be intuitive, instead of everyone having to search around for 10 minutes trying to figure it out :|